# Google App engine external database

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine

I've been searching and can't find an answer anywhere.  I also haven't had time to try it out either.

Is it possible, using java in the Google App Engine (GAE), to connect to a remote database.  Whether it MySql, SQLServer, etc.  Will it be allowed to make calls outside of it's domain?  Is it possible to even use the required libraries to make such a connection?

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing that you will find is the [Google Secure Data Connector](http://code.google.com/securedataconnector/).  All connections outbound from GAE are HTTP based, so you're very unlikely to get a jdbc type connection to a database server (MySql, SqlServer, etc).

Comment: Google Secure Data Connector is deprecated and doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you can try to tunnel JDBC through HTTP. It is possible.  For example here is free solution http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlgateway/ and here commercial http://www.idssoftware.com/jdbcdrv.html :)

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time using a REST API on the server that contains the database.  Depending on your needs (eg, do you need ad-hoc queries) you may want to choose a REST API with some flexibility.

There are quite a few simple REST-DB libraries around, such as http://phprestsql.sourceforge.net/

Though you may want to simply roll your own using http://www.playframework.org/ or http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#rest

Answer (score 0):

Dont use HTTP for DB connections as it is less secure.

Use CLoud SQL instead (jdbc type connection, mysql like queries and drivers in jars)

[getting started with cloud sql](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/getting-started)

[an easy video for java + cloud sql + app engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cv-q6Mdxe5M)