# Google app engine only as database store

Tags: database, google-app-engine

I am currently developing a php application hosted in my server. I want to store the database data in a more secure place rather than my own server. Can I use google app engine only to store and retrieve data without creating a java or python app? If thats possible how can I access data? Using a special service or I can directly connect to db like connecting to a mysql server and execute sql commands lik select, insert etc?

Answer (score 2):

Storing your data on App Engine will not magically grant you extra security. If an attacker compromises your server, they will be able to compromise the interface you have to your datastore and do whatever they wish.

A much better approach would be to learn best-practices for secure web development, and endeavour to ensure your app will not be compromised.

Answer (score 0):

They have a module called remote_api, but it has some restrictions. Check it out:
http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/appengine/articles/remote_api.html

Comment: Accessing remote API from PHP is not supported and would be an enormous amount of effort to implement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to access datastore in App engine. I assume you use mysql or other relational database for your php application. But app engine provide a schemaless object datastore. In that case you need some java or python app for preparing data to store in datastore. Check below links as well.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466420/google-app-engine-external-database