# Using JDBC on Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: oracle, google-app-engine, jdbc

GAE doesn't support JDBC but is there a way to use it anyway? Is there a way to **connect to an external Oracle db** to store structured information using the RDBMS pattern? Is the a wrapper or a runtime lib that makes it possible to **connect to an external RDBMS using JDBC**?

I don't want to use GAE's in-house MySQL cloud hack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google App engine external database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466420/google-app-engine-external-database)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open sockets on GAE, that's why you cannot open a JDBC connection for any outside RDBMS.

BTW, today they launched a trusted tester program for sockets on GAE:
http://googleappengine.blogspot.com.br/2012/09/app-engine-172-released.html

But I believe this is not the case they are trying to address