# Apps Script Database connectivity

Tags: google-apps-script, database-connection

I tried  Apps Script JDBC connectivity to an external Database . It always says: failed to establish database connection . Did Google deprecated connectivity to external database server outside cloud ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working like a charm. Check if you are using getConnection or getCloudSQLConnetion. The second one is to be used only with Cloud SQL.

The example below is working:

```
function doGet(){
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('datatable').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function getSql(){  
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://sql4.freesqldatabase.com:3306/sql427377', 'sql427377', 'my_pass');
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var results = stmt.executeQuery("select name, location, address, phone, fax from     person");
  Logger.log(results);
  var resultsArray = [];
  while(results.next()) {
    resultsArray.push({'name': results.getString(1),
                  'location' : results.getString(2),
                  'address' : results.getString(3),
                  'phone' : results.getString(4),
                  'fax' : results.getString(5)});
  }
  return JSON.stringify(resultsArray);
}
```

Live version [here](https://script.google.com/d/1P9-oDQDk9t3xAj5i80RqBG8vojsmTQa79ZRc28e0o0NQiEkk4aL8q77c/edit?usp=drive_web).

Comment: Wow , Thanks for your help Bro .Appreciate your time

Comment: Please mark the aswer as correct, it's important to my rank :)

Comment: Is it possible to connect to external MYSQL using Google App Engine GWT ? Can you share an example ?

Comment: IT's possible but improbable. Check this discussion:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466420/google-app-engine-external-database